# UnidentifiedImageError at /login/ cannot identify image file 'C:\\Users\\sudha\\django_project\\media\\default.jpg'

Tags: python, django

views.py/blog:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView,
    DetailView,
    CreateView,
    UpdateView,
    DeleteView
)
from .models import Post


def home(request):
    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/user_posts.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')


class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post


class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['Your_Name','city','phone','cost']
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)


class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title','content','phone']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False


class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = '/'

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False


def about(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/about.html', {'title': 'About'})
```

views.py/users:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in')
            return redirect('/login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'user/register.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=request.user.profile)
                                   
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }

    return render(request, 'user/profile.html', context)
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','password1','password2']

class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email']

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        field = ['image']
        exclude = ['fields']
```

models.py/users:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image
# Create your models here.

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',upload_to="profile_pics")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile,self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300,300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

and this is the tree:

```
C:.
├───blog
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───static
│   │   └───blog
│   ├───templates
│   │   └───blog
│   └───__pycache__
├───django_project
│   └───__pycache__
├───media
│   └───profile_pics
└───users
    ├───migrations
    │   └───__pycache__
    ├───templates
    │   └───user
    └───__pycache__
```

Iam not even able to login to my superuser please help me solve this bug and I guess I have not made any mojor changes to this since Iam working on this. This worked first but now it's not! Help me figure it out please.
Iam a django developer and this is really stopping me to complete my project faster.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the default.jpg image inside media folder is infact a .JPG. Do not rename png or other image files. This worked for me and I hope it helps